# C++ including from the other directory doesn't work

Tags: c++, gcc, include, g++

Yes, I know there's like 100000000 questions like this on this site. I spent 2 hours lurking SO to find out what am I doing wrong. This is my projects directory tree:

[image]

`main.cpp` starts with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "XD.hpp"
```

(`lib/XD.hpp` or `<XD>` doesn't work as well)

I tried many other combination, I even did `-I/home/frynio/Desktop/projects/sdizo1/lib`, but it still doesn't work. Do you guys see what am I doing wrong here?

I know this will be massively downvoted, but I'd rather spend time working on my project rather than trying to figure out this thing.

Comment: How about `-I./lib` ?

Comment: Sometimes stuff like this also happens on copy pasting and accidentally including some strange non visible characters. Try typing the #include "XD.hpp" line again.

Comment: Try running gcc with -v flag. It should tell you where it looks for headers.

Comment: Normal convention is to call a directory containing header files "include" and a directory containing libraries (collections of compiled objects which don't make a complete program but can be linked into one) "lib".

Comment: The one with `./lib` works. Why though? What does the single dot do? (using two would be taking advantage of relative paths)

Comment: When `/home/frynio/Desktop/projects/sdizo1` is your working directory, `-Isdizo1/lib` makes the compiler look in `/home/frynio/Desktop/projects/sdizo1/sdizo1/lib`.

Comment: By working directory you mean the directory I call `g++` from?

Comment: Single dot in `./lib` is expanded by most shells to be the current working directory (which would be relative to the location of the Makefile in your example).

Answer (score 2):

It should look something like this

```
#include "../lib/XD.hpp"
```

Comment: Thats just using relative path, right? I mean `..` gets me to the previous directory?

Comment: I think the better solution is provided by P0W: use `-I./lib`. Should the include file move to somewhere else, all includes for `XD.hpp` must be changed. With the `-I` option only a makefile must be changed.